# Force new line for some items in collection view - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view with multiple sections. Collection view data source is

```
dataSource = [Section]
```

Each section is having data members as below

```
Section = {id, [arr1], [arr2]}
```

Here, *id* is assigned as section header label. Currently, I am able to generate and insert cells for all the items in *arr1* and *arr2*. But they are continuously inserted under the section. I want to be able to insert cells in *arr2* starting on a new line even if there is space left after inserting the last item in *arr1*. My view controller subclasses *UICollectionViewDataSource*, *UICollectionViewDelegate*, *UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout*. What would be the most elegant and flexible way to achieve this? Am I missing anything?

Below is what I have in collectionview(cellForItemAt: ). *Resources* is *arr1* and *ResourceDesktops* is *arr2*.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.item < sections[indexPath.section].resources.count {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: resourceReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedsViewCell

            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                cell.imageView.accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
            }

            cell.image = UIImage(named: sections[indexPath.section].resources[indexPath.item].imageName)
            cell.resourceLabel.text = sections[indexPath.section].resources[indexPath.item].resourceName
            cell.resourceLabel.sizeToFit()

            var labelFrame = cell.resourceLabel.frame
            labelFrame = CGRect(x: labelFrame.origin.x, y: labelFrame.origin.y, width: labelWidth, height: labelFrame.height)
            cell.resourceLabel.frame = labelFrame

            return cell

        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: resourceDesktopReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ResourceDesktopViewCell

            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                cell.imageView.accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
            }

            cell.resourceLabel.text = sections[indexPath.section].resourceDesktops[indexPath.item - sections[indexPath.section].resources.count].resourceName
            cell.resourceLabel.sizeToFit()

            var labelFrame = cell.resourceLabel.frame
            labelFrame = CGRect(x: labelFrame.origin.x, y: labelFrame.origin.y, width: labelWidth, height: labelFrame.height)
            cell.resourceLabel.frame = labelFrame

            return cell
        }
}
```

Comment: what's in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`?

Comment: Updated question description with collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) :)

Comment: @staticVoidMan In the "else" part, I want to start inserting on a new row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITableView` instead of `UICollectionView` for whole data.
In details you can use 2 `UICollectionViews` and one *label* in each cell of `UITableView`

Comment: Thank you for the inputs! I was wondering if it can be done using a collection view alone because delegating data and including a search controller with UITableView and 2 UICollectionView seems to complicate the logic.